# is it possible to return the newest insert record when using rust diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using rust diesel `diesel = { version = "1.4.8", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }` to insert some record, this is my code looks like:

```
pub fn add_bill_book(request: &Json<BillBookRequest>, login_user_info: &LoginUserInfo) -> BillBook {
    let connection = config::connection("FORTUNE_DATABASE_URL".to_string());
    let bill_book_record = BillBookAdd{
        created_time: get_current_millisecond(),
        updated_time: get_current_millisecond(),
        deleted: 0,
        creator: login_user_info.userId,
        remark: None,
        bill_book_template_id: request.billBookTemplateId,
        contents: None
    };
    diesel::insert_into(crate::model::diesel::fortune::fortune_schema::bill_book::table)
        .values(&bill_book_record)
        .on_conflict_do_nothing()
        .execute(&connection)
        .unwrap();
    // return the newest insert record;
}
```

this code works fine, but I was wonder is it possible to return the inserted record when return this function? this command only return the effected rows right now. Or should I get the inserted id an query the record by id?

Comment: The "Inserting Data" example on the [home page](https://diesel.rs/) says: "If you need data from the rows you inserted, just change execute to `get_result` or `get_results`. Diesel will take care of the rest."